# Is Gradle's systemProp for JVM or Operating System property values?

Tags: android, gradle

If you read [11.2. Gradle properties and system properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

It says I can use the gradle `-D` flag to pass in a systemProp or in the `gradle.properties` of the root project I can declare a systemProp variable to declare these. In terms of gradle, what is the difference between a systemProp and a regular property in the `gradle.properties` file? Is a system property for the JVM? And also what if I wanted to make a OS environment variable can that be done from gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I understand now.  There is a disctinction between a gradle property and a system property. When we set a gradle property using for example -P on the command line or including it in the gradle.properties file it adds properties to your build file only.

However, if we use a system property then it also gets added to the gradle build properties BUT its also added to the JVM. So when i call in java code **System.getProperty(String propertyName)** the system property will be available. So in android it would be like the BuildConfig that many developers use. Its a way to pass properties to the JVM.